# Autowiring without an explicit Import statement seems to still work

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java Spring application and I am trying to understand how an Autowire bean is being injected even though I explicitly do not use it in the @import annotation. My code looks like this:

```
package com.pkg.test.configuration;

@Configuration
public class MySpringBeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public void constructMyBean() {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Here's the class which uses the Config

```
package com.pkg.test.configuration;

@Configuration
@Import({BlahClassConfig.class})
public class MySpringBeanConfig() {

    @Autowired private BlahClassConfig BlahClassConfig;
    @Autowired private MySpringBeanConfig MySpringBeanConfig;

    @Bean
    public void constructMyBean() {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

I have a class to perform a package scan as wel:

```
package com.pkg.test.configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.pkg.test.configration" })
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

Now, I have no complaints that the first Autowire for the MySpringBeanConfig is not existent or an error which says cannot be autowired. This somehow builds fine as well. Is there a reason why this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works due to the `@ComponentScan` annotation. It causes the `com.pkg.test.configuration` package to be scanned for all components, configurations, etc. So your `MySpringBeanConfig` gets found and processed.